# PlayReady Develop The License Server Yourself

Tags: drm, playready

I am new to PlayReady DRM, I am trying to develop the **PlayReady License Server** by **myself**.
I have gone through the entire document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/playready/
but, still can not find the guide to develop a PlayReady License Server by myself, where I can find that documentation/guide?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign a license agreement with Microsoft for access to the necessary SDK to do this.

The license agreement itself is free, but to receive an agreement, you will need to purchase a EV codesigning certificate.

Relevant links:

- https://www.microsoft.com/playready/licensing/
- https://www.microsoft.com/playready/licensing/server/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.media.drm